# Serialize HashMap like a Collection Property

Tags: jaxb, hashmap

Here I got two classes "Student" and "Course":

```
@XmlRootElement
class Student {
    private String name;
    private HashMap<String, Course> courses;

    public Student() {}
    public Student(String name, HashMap<String, Course> courses) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.courses = courses;
    }
    // -------------------------getters
    @XmlAttribute(name="name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "course")
    public HashMap<String, Course> getCourses() {
        return courses;
    }

    //---------------------------setters

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public void setCourses(HashMap<String, Course> courses) {
        this.courses = courses;
    }

}



@XmlRootElement
class Course {
    private String id;
    private String name;

    public Course() {}
    public Course(String id, String name) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @XmlID
    @XmlAttribute(name = "id")
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    @XmlAttribute(name = "name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

I want to serialize the Student class using JaxB annotations to something like the following:

```
<Student name="David">
    <courses>
        <Course id="1" name="Fundamentals of Programming"/>
        <Course id="2" name="Advanced Programming">
    </courses>
</Student>
```

Note that I want courses field of the Student to be HashMap and when unmarshalling the serialized Object use id as the key for each Course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an `XmlAdapter` for this use case.  An `XmlAdapter` allows you to programmatically convert an object to another type for the purpose of marshalling/unmarshalling.  For your use case you will convert the `HashMap` to an instance of an object that has a collection of `Course`.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xmladapter-jaxbs-secret-weapon.html